# Google Maps: "map is not defined"

Tags: jquery, xml, google-maps-api-3

I'm experimenting with google maps panTo. I have a JQuery application map. and have tried the simple code.

```js
function movemap(latlong) {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latlong);
    map.panTo(myLatlng);
}
```

It says `map is not Defined` in the firebug console. So that means that I have not defined it. So how do I define it.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with the tutorial example is that "map" is a local variable defined and used ONLY inside the initialize() function. If you want to reference it outside that function, which is what you are trying to do, you must define it outside the function. In this case the tutorial should be rewritten like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var map;
  function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);
  }

</script>
```

Note that "map" is now define outside any function so now any javascript function can reference it.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to go through the [tutorial](https://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html); here's how they've created a new map object:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);
  }

</script>
```

where `map_canvas` is

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line `var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latlong);` it looks as if you have two variables running together.

Should it not be `var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);`, with the two variable split by a comma?

Comment: The variable from the link is onclick(445223, -0124455) for example

Comment: ok.  But `google.maps.LatLng` needs to be passed two arguments, one for latitude and one for longitude.  Is your onClick suppling the string `445223, -0124455` exactly as is, with the comma separation?

Comment: Yes it is. But just in case I have changed it to fit with a comma separation as in your example. It still is not the cause of the problem

Comment: Did you also change the parameters for the function, too?  Right now it also reads `function movemap(latlong)` without a separation.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is that you need a variable "map" to be global. So instead of initializing it in "initialize function" you simply declare it somewhere in main block,

so instead of this:

```
function initialize(){
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(49.6327939,15.4174414),
        zoom: 6,            
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);  
}
```

you'll do this:

```
var map;
function initialize(){
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(49.6327939,15.4174414),
        zoom: 6,            
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);      
}
```